# How to run a .py file through a batch file using Command line

Tags: windows, python-2.7, batch-file, command-line

I want to run my .py file in .bat file in Windows, and since at the end of the script, the window closes, I want to tell the batch file to run the python file through opening Command line, so that at the end of the python file's execution, it will still stay open

Thank you for anybody's help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to run the file and then go to Command Prompt, so please tell me if you have issues with this.

```
echo off
cls
start /b filename.py
cls
cmd
```

If you want to read error messages or output, remove the second `cls`.

If you wanted to ask if the user wants to run it again once it is done, here is the code for that:

```
echo off
:run
cls
start /b  filename.py
cls
choice /c yn /n /m Run again? (y/n)
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto run
if %errorlevel% equ 2 exit
```

Or, if you want to do it from the command line, type `"C:\directory\filename.py"` in cmd.exe. If you don't know how to run cmd.exe, click the start button, type cmd.exe, and hit enter.

Once again, if you have any issues, please let me know. Sorry, I wasn't able to test this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tip - my py file named crop3 takes an image as input. When I try to run it through command, it opens a text file of the py file code. I've tried using:                                          .\crop3.py  file_path, no luck. Do you have any ideas