# couldnt write token to cache at: .cache

Tags: python, spotipy

[run display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21uT8.png)

when run it spits out the error couldnt write token to cache at: .cache but it still manages to grab whatever is playing. and each time it makes a request it reopens a auth page. it also doesnt save to any of the files. everything runs fine in pycharm using the main python environment.

````
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import requests
import time
#file locations
file_time_playing = "time_playing.txt"
file_time_playing_ms = "time_playing_ms.txt"
file_time_total = "time_total.txt"
file_time_total_ms = "time_total_ms.txt"


sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id = ".......",
                                              client_secret = ".......",
                                              redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080",
                                              scope = "streaming"))


song = ""

def track():
   print("======================")
   global song
   global currently_playing
   # print(sp.currently_playing())

   try:
       currently_playing = sp.currently_playing()
       #print(currently_playing)
       if song == str(currently_playing["item"]["name"]):
           print(song)
           play_time()
           return
       else:
           song = str(currently_playing["item"]["name"])
           print(song)

           with open("song.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
               f.write(song)
   except:
       pass




starttime = time.time()
while True:
   track()
   time.sleep(0.5 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 0.5))```
````

Answer (score 0):

i found a link to a git hub error and it suggested ruining it from a .bat i used the below links to solve my issue
https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/363

[How to run a .py file through a batch file using Command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650157/how-to-run-a-py-file-through-a-batch-file-using-command-line)